# error while trying to set onItemClickListener in ListView up

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/034WJ.png)

I am trying to make clickable items in `ListView`, and recivieng this kind of error.

```
ListView chHE = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvHE);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cities);
chHE.setAdapter(adapter);

chHE.getOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long l) {
        if (position == 0) {
            toast.show();
        }
    }
});
```

> Error:(52, 13) error: method getOnItemClickListener in class AdapterView
>   cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: no arguments
>   found: 
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends Adapter declared in class AdapterView

Comment: it should be `setOnItemClickListener();` not `getOnItemClickListener();`

Comment: You must use `setOnItemClickListener` not `getOnItemClickListener` !!!

Comment: you should read the error message at least before positng a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chHE.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
        if(position==0){
            toast.show();
        }
    }
});
```

maybe you have write in a mastake？change  get=>set

Answer (score 0):

you should remplace `getOnItemClickListener` to `setOnItemClickListener`

```
ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
            // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
            // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
      }
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //doSomeThing
    }
});
```